# How to implement javascript:history.back() in a server component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have a server component (using Next.js 13.4.1) that reads json files in local server, and I have a button on this component for users to go back to the previous page. Codes are as following:

```js
import 'server-only';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

function getLocalData() {
  // Read and return local data in the server
}

export default function Page() {
  const data = getLocalData();
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{ data }</div>
      <button onClick={() => router.back()}>Go back</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Running this code results with an error: "You have a Server Component that imports next/router. Use next/navigation instead.". After trying with 'next/navigation', I got another error: "Error: useRouter only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it.".

Is there any way for implementing simple javascript:history.back() in a server rendered component? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try adding `'use client';` at the top of your file after using `next/navigation`?

Comment: @Zserbinator Yes I tried adding `'use client'`, and I got an error: `You're importing a component that needs server-only. That only works in a Server Component but one of its parents is marked with "use client", so it's a Client Component.` Moreover, I need it to be a server component to read local data in server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if we imagine that somehow something like `router.back()` magically works with a server component, you will have another problem - server components **cannot** have any interactivity or event listeners, e.g. `onClick()`, `onChange()` etc (also no state or effect hooks, no browser api etc, [check this table for comparison](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#when-to-use-server-and-client-components)).

To solve it you can make a small client component (see docs: [Moving Client Components to the Leaves](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#moving-client-components-to-the-leaves)) and have that logic there:

```
// // ButtonThatHasClientSideLogic is a Client Component, move your logic there
import ButtonThatHasClientSideLogic from './ButtonThatHasClientSideLogic'

// Page is a server component by default 
export default function Page() {
  const data = getLocalData();

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{ data }</div>
      <ButtonThatHasClientSideLogic />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the docs there are other patterns on how to use and mix server and client components:

https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#patterns